# Application is not installed, android

Tags: android

I made my android application and tested it on the AVD but when I want to install it on my phone, I get "application not installed"

what could cause this problem??

here is the Manifest.xml, I don't see any thing weird in it !!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dashboard_our"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.dashboard_our.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.dashboard_our.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.dashboard_our.Hotels"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.dashboard_our.Restaurants"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.dashboard_our.About"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.dashboard_our.PrayTime"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.dashboard_our.Airports"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.dashboard_our.Currency_convert"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.dashboard_our.Translator"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_translate" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.dashboard_our.WeatherActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.dashboard_our.PlaceDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".PlaceDetails" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.example.dashboard_our.Todo"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.dashboard_our.Ocr"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.dashboard_our.TodoDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>


        <provider
            android:name=".contentprovider.MyTodoContentProvider"
            android:authorities="de.vogella.android.todos.contentprovider" >
        </provider>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="API-KEY" />





    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, the problem was in my phone, I had to format my phone in order to work

Answer (score 0):

any error from a DDMS? also you can try looking for .apk file from your project source and installing  the app into the device.

Comment: no errors from DDMS, the code works perfectly on the AVD, I tried to move it via Bluetooth!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check "allow installation from non market applications" in your phone settings?
Did you remove an SD card around the time of installation?

Comment: If you removed an SD card. You app is on the old one. There is a lot of possibilities if not. Multiple installs, different package name. Delete App from your phone and try again.

Comment: I just tried to install it an hour ago it worked, but now it won't.
I added a library (Parse-1.3.3) and then it refused to be installed, could it be the reason for this problem?

Comment: I don't see how but there are far more knowledgeable people on here that may be able to help. You say "refused" to be be installed. What happens? Are you using eclipse? I just reread your post, obviously not.  Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have declared Main Activity twice inside AndroidManifest.xml. Delete one.

Another solution is if you haven't signed your app, you need to sign it. As the docs say ***All applications must be signed. The system will not install an application on an emulator or a device if it is not signed***. Go here for more information:  [Android App Signing](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Comment: I checked, I declared it only once

Comment: Ok the file looks good, final question: Have you signed your app?

Comment: no I haven't, I installed it before on my device without signing it

Comment: Sign it. Tell me how it goes.

Comment: How could I sign it??

Comment: I think the problem is in my device, I tried it on another device and it worked!!